# How to connect AS400 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, db2, ibm-midrange

For a little while now, I've been looking how to try a connection to AS400 with Laravel 7.

I use this package : https://github.com/cooperl22/laravel-ibmi

I add laravel-ibmi to your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "cooperl/laravel-ibmi": "^7.0"
}
```

Use composer to install this package.

```
$ composer update
```

Run on the command line from the root of my project:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish
```

And set credentials in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=ibmi
DB_HOST=********
DB_PORT=********
DB_DATABASE=********
DB_USERNAME=********
DB_PASSWORD=********
```

I try a connection with tinket but i have this message :

```
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> DB::connection();
PDOException with message 'could not find driver
```

I should set my credentials in app/config/db2.php, not in .env ?

UPDATE

I install the unixODBC

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/za/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Download ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli_linux390x64_v11.5.tar.gz

```
tar -xavf ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli_linux390x64_v11.5.tar.gz
cd odbc_cli
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ibm/clidriver
sudo cp -r clidriver/* /opt/ibm/clidriver
```

Edit the odbcinst.ini

```
[Db2]
Description=Db2 Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/clidriver/lib/libdb2o.so
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1
```

Edit odbc.ini for the test

```
[sample]
Description     = Test to DB2
Driver          = Db2
```

but when i try i got this message

```
export DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
isql -v sample db2inst1 ibmdb2
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/ibm/clidriver/lib/libdb2o.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

UPDATE 2

I go to https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/633843

Click Downloads for IBM i Access Client Solutions

When prompted, log in with my IBMid

Scroll down, and next to ACS Linux App Pkg, select Download now

After that i have installed ibm-iaccess-1.1.0.13-1.0.x86_64.rpm, i see it automatically adds the IBM i Access ODBC Driver to odbcinst.ini.

Edit odbc.ini for the test

```
[sample]
Description     = Test to DB2
Driver          = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
```

But it's the bug is repeated (Whereas /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so exist).

```
isql -v sample
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

UPDATE 3

I enter this command

```
ldd /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4830e000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f1fdc97e000)
    libcwbcore.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1fdc5f5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1fdc257000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1fdc03f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1fdbc4e000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f1fdba44000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1fdb825000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1fdce6c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1fdb621000)
```

I did that afterwards.

```
cp /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbcore.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

```
isql -v sample
[S1000][unixODBC][IBM][Pilote ODBC System i Access]Le nom de syst�me requis pour la connexion est manquant.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: Get your ODBC connection to the database on AS/400 working at the ubuntu command line (for example in bash, using __isql__ command), __before__ you try with PHP.  That makes problem determination easier.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "could not find driver" might be a good start to check your server's configuration

Comment: Which driver type are you using? I don't think the credentials are the problem.

Comment: i update my first message

Comment: If you do not have a Db2-connect server (or license)  then the Db2-driver you downloaded is the *wrong* driver.  For  i series, odbc access for linux/windows is best provided by IBM i access, see https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions

Comment: Now that you have installed a suitable Db2 driver, check the output of command `ldd /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so` . there should be no missing dependencies. You may need to adjust LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I have this : `libcwbcore.so => not found`

Comment: Your "odbc.ini" is missing information, example SYSTEM = (ip address of i-series or hostname), and maybe more like port, userid, password, database etc.  Be sure to __fully__ read the Installation and Usage Guide and check pre-requisites, troubleshooting (cwbping, cwbtrc) and redbook referenced link to redbook.

Comment: Ok i find ! thanks you sooo much for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP and Laravel it is wise to get the unixODBC working at the command line before trying to get it working with PHP. The reason is that troubleshooting is easier when you have fewer components to test. It also helps with separation of responsibilities.

The solution was to download and install
a suitable Db2-driver for ODBC/CLI on Linux specifically to work with i-series (AS/400) from IBM website at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions).

The other small footprint clidriver (supplied by IBM) cannot communicate with i-series unless you go via a Db2-connect gateway or have a Db2-connect licence (separate purchase). So it is usually more effective to use the IBM i access product instead. The clidriver works correctly without needing a license or Db2-connect, only when the target Db2-server runs on Linux or Unix variant or Microsoft Windows.

This `IBM i access client` product has a PDF document included *"Installation and Usage Guide"* which has helpful information, and several links to useful resources.

After installation, it is necessary to properly configure both the `odbcjinst.ini` (which details the driver) and the `odbc.ini`(which details the data soruces) (or `.odbc.ini` for user DSNs) for use with the driver supplied by the IBM i access client product.

Instructions for completing the `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini` are available on the [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) website.

Test the connection to the i series with the `isql` tool, to verify that unixODBC is able to connect and use SQL queries.

The IBM i access product also has troubleshooting tools that includes `cwbping` and `cwbtrc` commands among others, which exercise the Db2-driver independently of unixODBC.

Once `isql` successfully connects to the i series database, you are now ready to configure PHP to use the driver in the normal way. You can then test with Laravel.

Remember to ensure that your linux shell sets the correct `LANG` environment variable to match your country and your character encoding before accessing the database (which require the relevant `locale` to be installed), otherwise codepage conversion may give unexpected results.